# How to return IQueryable from an SQL expression?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am getting the following error trying to query from my database using C#:

***LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'MyProject.Models.DB.Department getDepartment()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.***

In my controller I have:

```
var query = db.Activities.AsQueryable();
query = query.Where(x => rs.department.Contains(x.getDepartment().id));
```

In my model I have the following method which returns the correct `Department` for an `Activity`. I know the problem is that I am executing the query when I do the `.First()`, but I can't find a way to return this as a `IQueryable` result:

```
public partial class Activity
{
   public Department getDepartment()
    {
        return db.Departments.SqlQuery( "" +
            "SELECT * FROM " +
                "[snt].[Departments] " +
            "INNER JOIN( " +
                "SELECT " +
                    "[Users].departments_id AS id " +
                "FROM " +
                    "[snt].[Users], " +
                    "[snt].[People], " +
                    "[snt].[EventPerson], " +
                    "[snt].[EventPersonTask], " +
                    "[snt].[Tasks], " +
                    "[snt].[Events], " +
                    "[snt].[Activities] " +
                "WHERE " +
                    "[snt].[Activities].id = {0} AND " +
                    "[snt].[Events].id = [snt].[Activities].events_id AND " +
                    "[snt].[EventPerson].events_id = [snt].[Events].id AND " +
                    "[snt].[EventPerson].people_id = [snt].[People].id AND " +
                    "[snt].[EventPersonTask].tasks_id = [snt].[Tasks].id AND " +
                    "[snt].[EventPersonTask].eventperson_id = [snt].[EventPerson].id AND " +
                    "[snt].[Tasks].name = 'owner' AND " +
                    "[snt].[Users].is_active = 1 AND " +
                    "[snt].[Users].people_id = [snt].[People].id" +
            " ) AS x " +
            "ON " +
                "x.id = [Departments].id", this.id).First();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not saying it's possible, but I would begin by removing the call to `.First()` in your `getDepartment()` function.  `.First()` will execute the query, which is, apparently, not what you want.

Comment: I have already tested the method and it is working fine, it returns the expected `Department`, the problem comes when in my controller I try to use this query inside another query... like shown in the first piece of code. I get the error that I am trying to avoid.

Comment: IQueryable represents a query. `SqlQuery` already returns an IQueryable. What's the point of this code though (never mind the obsolete JOIN syntax)? Those JOINs should be generated by the ORM itself based on relations between the entities.The ORM's query will probably be simpler too and easier to optimize - the subquery isn't necessary

Comment: The good thing about StackOverflow is that you can always find people who encourages you with nice comments instead of actual help, like "Obsloete joins" ... Really nice to come and ask a question and get discouraged instead of receiving an actual answer to your question.